# array with the same length

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array's, array 1 is students (size is 148) second array are internships (size is 106). 
Now I want these 2 array's have the same length, my question is how can I add empty elements to array internship with PHP, or how can I delete some from array student?

Maybe I explain why, that's my goal. I implement a generic algorithm to assign each student to a internship. It's importent that these 2 array's have the same length.

I have included a sample of the above array's.

array student

```
 array(148) {  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "804868"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "804869"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "705169"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "805148"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "702342"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "803176"
    }
  }
```

array internships

```
enter code herearray(106) { [0]=> string(18) "Pcv (campus Aalst)" [1]=> string(53) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Walravens Marc )" [2]=> string(54) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Peeters Stefaan )" [3]=> string(35) "psychiatrie (campus Vercruysselaan)" [4]=> string(39) "interne geneeskunde (campus Loofstraat)" [5]=> string(40) "interne geneeskunde (campus Kennedylaan)" [6]=> string(29) "heelkunde (campus Loofstraat)" [7]=> string(30) "heelkunde (campus Kennedylaan)" [8]=> string(33) "heelkunde (campus Vercruysselaan)" [9]=> string(38) "logopedie (groepspraktijk Logomatopee)" [10]=> string(41) "logopedie (Koninklijk Instituut Spermali)" [11]=> string(34) "Fysieke activiteit (To Walk Again)" [12]=> string(53) "algemene en plastische heelkunde ( AZ AZ Oudenaarde )" [13]=> string(38) "dermatologie (campus Maria Middelares)" [14]=> string(29) "NKO (campus Maria Middelares)" [15]=> string(38) "dermatologie (campus Maria Middelares)" [16]=> string(38) "Fysieke activiteit (Beweegkamp Vlabus)" [17]=> string(43) "Hoofdverpleegkundige ( UZ UZ Gent Urologie)" [18]=> string(66) "Opleidingscoördinator ( Onderwijsinstelling Arteveldehogeschool )" [19]=> string(90) "Verpleegkundig Specialist ( UMC Universitair Medisch Centrum Universitair Medisch Centrum)" [20]=> string(31) "Mss ( AZ Nikolaas campus Hamme)" [21]=> string(74) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Cuigniez Pascale PR Cuigniez Pascale)" [22]=> string(53) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Smesman Jeroen )" [23]=> string(103) "Verpleegkundig Specialist ( AZ Algemeen Stedelijk Ziekenhuis Aalst Algemeen Stedelijk Ziekenhuis Aalst)" [24]=> string(33) "Pcv ( AZ Jan Yperman Ziekenhuis )" [25]=> string(76) "Mss ( AZ Gezondheidszorg Oostkust campus Blankenberge - AZ Koningin Fabiola)" [26]=> string(81) "Mss ( AZ Gezondheidszorg Oostkust campus Knokke - AZ Onze-Lieve-Vrouw Ter Linden)"
```

Comment: There is no technical difficulty to add or delete items from arrays. Can you precise the rules you need to decide what has to be deleted, and what has to be added and with what?

Comment: May I ask why you need both arrays to have the same length ?

Comment: The fact that you feel you need to add empty elements as part of your coding solution here tells me you haven't organized the data correctly. I don't know what your database looks like but you should have a table for scholarships, a table for students, and a table linking the two. This will allow you to have third normal form normalized data. Sure, there are ways to extend the arrays as noted below, but I think what would really be best in a situation like this is to go back to the drawing board and think things through a little better from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend an array to a given length [array_pad()](http://php.net/array-pad)

```
$array = array_pad($array, $size, null);
```

Will add `null` until the array has reached the given size.

To cut some elements of to a given size: [array_slice()](http://php.net/array-slice) with `0` as start offset.

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, $size);
```